# Renamed APK with the time of building does not run

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, apk, build.gradle

I use this code in `build.gradle` file of my module to rename the output APK

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                def file = output.outputFile
                def formattedDate = new Date().format('yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm')
                output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, file.name.replace(".apk",
                        "-" + formattedDate + ".apk"))
            }
        }
```

When I press "Run", I receive the APK here `build/outputs/apk/app-debug-2016_01_11_13_23.apk` and get an error in the Run console:

```
The APK file .../build/outputs/apk/app-debug-2016_01_11_13_21.apk does not exist on disk.
```

Every new time when I press "Run", I receive the new APK in the `/build/outputs/apk/` folder but the error is the same. It looks like an Android Studio uses the old value of the app's name.

I use this Run configuration: 
[image]

Feel free to give any kind of suggestions.

Comment: "Feel free to give any kind of suggestions." -- that's really going to open you up to all sorts of jokes. Like this one ;)

Comment: I'm pretty confused with this kind of asynchronous issue. I really open for any help. Please, use your power of jokes to try to answer :P

Comment: Facing same issue :(

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199676) in current version 1.5.1 of android studio.
I had the same problem as you but I only wanted to rename the release apk.

So I ended up with this quick workaround to rename the apk only when the selected signinConfig is the release one:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.signingConfig.getName() == android.signingConfigs.release.getName()) {
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def file = output.outputFile
            def formattedDate = new Date().format('yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm')
            output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, file.name.replace(".apk",
                    "-" + formattedDate + ".apk"))
        }
    }
}
```

All the debug build will have the same name, so it doesn't matter if Android Studio has difficulties refreshing the apk name before uploading it to the device